# Format DATETIME from MYSQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have a field in my database called 'DateTime' and the following lines of code:

```
echo "Date/Time: ";
echo $row['DateTime'];
```

How do I format it so that instead of being like this:'2013-02-07 22:14:56', it will be like this: '07/02/13 - 22:14'

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative would be to have MySQL format the DATETIME value as a string in the desired format, using the DATE_FORMAT function.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`DateTime`,'%d/%m/%y - %H:%i') AS `DateTime`
   ...
```

No change required to your PHP code except for the SQL text sent to the database server.

This approach can very efficient, and reduce the amount of code you need, if all you are doing with this string is displaying it. If you are doing any sort of manipulation on this value, then casting the string value returned from MySQL resultset into a datetime object is probably a better way to go.

---

A demonstration of the DATE_FORMAT function:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2013-02-07 22:14:56','%d/%m/%y - %H:%i') AS `DateTime`

DateTime
----------------
07/02/13 - 22:14
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could use:
DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d H:i:s',$row['DateTime']); this will give you a datetime object, which are quite nice to work with.

Answer (score 1):

how to output date into Year textbox Month textbox Day textbox

```
$book_date = $myrow["Publication_Day"];
$book_year = Date("Y", strtotime($book_date));
```

Answer (score 1):

$timestamp contains ur date & time in any format.....................

date('Y/m/d - H:i',strtotime($timeStamp));

Answer (score 0):

```
echo date('d/m/y H:i', strtotime($row['DateTime']));
```

See [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) for more detail on the functions from the docs

Comment: Thank you, trivial question but helped anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$mytime = strtotime('2013-06-07 22:14:56');
$newDate = date('m/d/y - G:i', $mytime);
echo $newDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative using [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php). If you're working with timezones this code can be easily modified to handle that.

```
$datetime = new DateTime('2013-02-07 22:14:56');
echo $datetime->format('d/m/y H:i');
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/EJyzhY)